# How to revert a previous commit on the master branch and save the code in another branch?

Tags: git, github

I just made a push on the production site and all the changes were on master. But i realized the code that i pushed needs to be altered so i need to revert the last commit but take all that code from that commit and put it in another branch so i can push it later....any way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to fix this.

Here's what I'd do (with a bit of extra insurance)

Assuming your HEAD is in 'the wrong place' (no pun intended), you can

```
 git branch rescue
 # you are still on master
 git reset HEAD^ # soft resets the last commit
 git push -f     # to undo the push - beware of other users of the push-branch
```

Now edit / rescue you commit in-place (because the last commit's changes are now pending again). If there is an emergency, you can always checkout the `rescue` branch, which is simply a copy of the HEAD when you started this post.

Comment: do i do this on my local ....basically the local is where i am doing the push and the production is where i do "git pull origin master"

Comment: You do it where you wanted to fix the problems (so, presumably the local). Did you already `pull` the production side? If not you're good, but otherwise, production will have to be `--force` pulled as well

Comment: also ...i realized it was about 3 commit ....so is there a way to alter what you showed above to revert the last three commit instead of the last commit

Comment: Yup. `git reset HEAD~3`. After fixing the central repo (using the push -f), just do another pull on production. You specify `--force` because it will see that it isn't a fast-forward change

Comment: so after i do this git reset HEAD~3 on the local and then i run git push -f on local also then on the production i do git pull origin master --force or do i do a push from the local first

Comment: you push what you want to pushed: in your case, _after_ reset the last three commits. Keep in mind that the changes of those last commits will be pending in your working copy. If you did the `rescue` branch _first_ you'll always have that backup, so you can't screw it up too badly.

Comment: also how do i now take all these commits and put them into a new branch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4984/discussion-between-sehe-and-tamer)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to fix already pushed commit with the correcting revert commit. You may also safely start your experiments from the reverted commit. See also [Git Community Book, Undoing in Git](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html)

```
git revert HEAD
git push
```

Rewriting already published commits is considered as a bad practice (quote from the same section):

> Fixing committed mistakes
>
> If you make a commit that you later wish you hadn't, there are two
>   fundamentally different ways to fix the problem:
>
> You can create a new commit that undoes whatever was done by the old
>   commit. This is the correct thing if your mistake has already been
>   made public.
>
> You can go back and modify the old commit. You should never do this if
>   you have already made the history public; git does not normally expect
>   the "history" of a project to change, and cannot correctly perform
>   repeated merges from a branch that has had its history changed.

See also section "The Perils of Rebasing" from [Pro Git, Rebasing](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html) why this is not good.

Answer (score 0):

2 steps:

1) do a branch off the current master.( Saving your code so you can do the fix. )

2) Roll back 1 Commit in master. [git reset --hard HEAD~1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-last-git-commit)